# Share network service

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-shares

I have a HTTP server on my Virtualbox machine, and I want to access this server from other devices on my network (physical network outside the host machine).

I tried sharing the "Host Only Network Adapter" but that doesn't work. Is there a way to access my virtual machine from other devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have mine configured and I can access it from anywhere.

[image: Network Settings]